# Nested dictionary values are empty, C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

i have responses on the following form:

```
page1Title:507
page1URL:577
```

And my code, which should map each property of a page to that page-key in nested dictionary and do that for all pages:

```
 Dictionary<string,string> mapOfSinglePage = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> mapOfAllPages = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
string[] keys = { "title", "url","description","owner","cat", "pts" };
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                foreach (string key in keys) {
                    mapOfSinglePage[key] = Regex.Split(responses[i], "<br />")[Array.IndexOf(keys, key)].Split(':')[1];
                }
                mapOfAllPages[i + ". page"] = mapOfSinglePage;
                mapOfSinglePage.Clear();
            }
            String response = "";
            string help = "";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> kvp in mapOfAllPages)
            {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp2 in kvp.Value)
                {
                    help+= string.Format("Key : {0}, Value : {1}", kvp2.Key, kvp2.Value);
                }
                response+= string.Format("Key : {0}, Value : {1}", kvp.Key, help);
                help = "";
            }
                Response.Write(response);
```

Problem is, when i print it out, it comes out as

```
Key : 1. page, Value : Key : 2. page, Value : Key : 3. page
```

and so on. I  other words, the mapOfSinglePage dictionary is empty when assinged to mapOfAllPages

It seems like it would be the normal behaviour if the clear() of `mapOfSinglePage` dictionary was before the assignment to `mapOfAllPages` but it isnt the case.

Or am I printing it out wrong? It does not seem to be the case for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this bit:

```
  mapOfAllPages[i + ". page"] = mapOfSinglePage;
  mapOfSinglePage.Clear();
```

You are assuming that this makes a copy of `mapOfSinglePage` and puts that copy in `mapOfAllPages[i + ". page"]`, and then clears the original `Dictionary`.

It doesn't. It makes `mapOfAllPages[i + ". page"]` point to `mapOfSinglePage` *which is then cleared*.

You need to create a new `Dictionary` each time, and never clear it.

Comment: I was actually thinking that maybe its this, but i guess i couldn't believe it at these late hours. Marked!